# Can not install Pear Text_Diff

Tags: php, windows, pear

I try to install [Pear Text_Diff](http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Diff/redirected) by using

```
pear install Text_Diff
```

However, the it says

> no release avaiable for package "pear.php.net/Text_Diff". install failed.

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you install another package from pear? Which operating system? Which user-account?

Comment: when I install other package, like "pear install Holidays", it returned other errors: Failed to download pear/Date_Holidays within preferred state "stable", lastest release is version 0.21.6, stability alpha, use "channel://pear.php.net/Date_holidays-0.21.6" to install. install failed

Comment: That's different. Just wanted to know if it's specific to the package or not. What does `pear version` give? Are you running on windows, linux, mac osx or something else?

Comment: i am using windows 7, 32 bits, with XAMPP 3.1.0, i dont know pear version

Comment: You need to start a console (cmd) with administrator rights. Then enter `pear version` for the pear version. Also the install *should* (let's see) work then, too.

Comment: my pear version is 1.9.4. I run wit admin right, but still can not install

Comment: You can try `pear clear-cache` then `pear update-channels` and finally again `pear install Text_Diff`.

Comment: thanks alot. work like a charm.

Comment: I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PEAR on windows sometimes needs a little refresh running the following commands before install:

- `pear clear-cache`
- `pear update-channels`

And finally again:

- `pear install Text_Diff`